# How would I create a IP whitelist for tomcat?

Tags: ip, tomcat, whitelist

I'm extremely new to tomcat but I need to configure my company's tomcat server so that we can allow restricted IP addresses only.

I understand this is normally the job of the firewall but in this case that is not an option.

We are doing a deployment to the production server and while that's happening we need to be able to show a maintenance page run by Apache which rests in the same server as tomcat.

In this case, what would I need to do in order to only allow access to selected ip addresses to the whole tomcat server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Tomcat's [Remote Address Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter):

> The Remote Address Filter allows you to compare the IP address of the
>   client that submitted this request against one or more regular
>   expressions, and either allow the request to continue or refuse to
>   process the request from this client.

**Edit**: Which file to edit depends on whether you want the filter to apply to a single webapp or to all of them. From the same page linked above:

> Tomcat provides a number of Filters which may be configured for use
>   with all web applications using $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml or may be
>   configured for individual web applications by configuring them in the
>   application's WEB-INF/web.xml.

**Edit 2**: Here's an example for 3 IPv4 addresses:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value>x\.x\.x\.x|y\.y\.y\.y|z\.z\.z\.z</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```